# numpy objectarray.h compile error with MingW64

Tags: python, numpy, 64-bit, python-c-api

I'm trying to compile python cpp library using numpy arrayobject.h on Windows 7 x64.
It keeps showing errors. Could anybody help me out to fix them?

The error is like following.

```
ndarrayobject.h:139:52: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'npy_intp* {aka long long int*}' in argument passing
```

My Environment

- Windows 7 x64
- Python 2.7.10 x64
- Numpy 1.11.0
- MinGW64

And I set them up with [this site](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/).

With Python x86, there is no problem.

Comment: I found out my usage of numpy c api was wrong. npy_intp has big difference between x86 an x64, do not use int to set argument instead of npy_intp.